# How do I make the uri in a PyGTK LinkButton open in a browser on Windows?

Tags: windows, gtk, pygtk

I have created a PyGTK LinkButton on Windows. It contains a URI that I want to open in the user's browser.

```
gtk.LinkButton("http://www.mysite.com")
```

The documentation [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklinkbutton.html) suggests I need to provide a hook function to `gtk.link_button_set_uri_hook`. Is there a function built in to PyGTK that I can use cross-platform, or do I need to write my own Windows-specific function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? You don't have to supply an URI hook. Just provide the URI and the `LinkButton` will take care of the rest. Minimal example:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
w = Gtk.Window()
w.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
w.add(Gtk.LinkButton("http://google.com", "test"))
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

This creates a window with a single button that when clicked opens Google in the systems default web browser.
If for any reason this doesn't work, you can have a look at the **[`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser)** module in the Python standard library which provides cross-platform support (I don't know if this module is used in gtk internally as well, in this case it just wouldn't make a difference).

Comment: When I run the code above and click the button, I get an error from WinHttp. It looks like the program is trying to _fetch_ the URI instead of displaying it. This could be a configuration problem with my GTK install. Anyway, the webbrowser module works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one method which is working for me, on both Windows and Linux:

```
def _open_link(func, data=None):
    desktop.open(data)

gtk.link_button_set_uri_hook(_open_link)
```